# Shell script embedding Oracle PL/SQL code defining bind variable

Tags: sql, oracle, bash, plsql

If I run the below script, I am getting the error 
**SP2-0552: Bind variable "OUTRES" not declared.**
So, how to define the bind variable OUTRES and where to define?

```
#!/usr/bin/bash
sqlplus -s scott/tiger << EOF 
declare ret varchar2(10):= '0';
begin
  begin
    insert into mytab(col1) values(1);
  exception
    when others then
      ret:=ret||'1';
  end;
  select ret into :OUTRES from dual;
end;
/
quit
EOF
```

Answer (score 6):

If you want to declare the bind variable in `sqlplus`. use the `VAR` keyword.

```
sqlplus -s scott/tiger << EOF 
VAR OUTRES NUMBER;
BEGIN
  NULL; /* Your Statements */
END;
/
EOF
```

You can also try `quit :OUTRES` and

```
quit :OUTRES
EOF
MYRESULT=$?
echo $MYRESULT
```

It output the return status in `UNIX`.

```
#!/usr/bin/bash
sqlplus -s scott/tiger << EOF 
VAR OUTRES NUMBER;
declare ret varchar2(10):= '0';
begin
  begin
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'insert into mytab(col1) values(1)';
  exception
    when others then
      dbms_output.put_line(SQLERRM);
      ret:=ret||'1';
  end;
  :OUTRES := ret;
end;
/
quit :OUTRES
EOF
MYRESULT=$?
echo $MYRESULT
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply, but [Mahesh](http://stackoverflow.com/users/3093319/maheswaran-ravisankar) could you tell me where exactly in the above code, I should set the VAR (bind variable)?

Comment: By the way, if there is any error occurred in the PL/SQL code block for eg, invalid table name or column name, the error value always returned is 1 in spite of changing the ret to store some other value other than the 1.

Comment: you should declare before you run your pl/sql block, and after entering into sqlplus.

Comment: And, the PL/SQL will end up with compilation error, when the TABLE name is invalid. I edited my answer to do it using dynamic SQL.

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/usr/bin/bash
sqlplus -s scott/tiger << EOF 
declare 
ret varchar2(10):= '0';
OUTRES  varchar2(10);
begin
  begin
    insert into mytab(col1) values(1);
  exception
    when others then
      ret:=ret||'1';
  end;
  select ret into OUTRES from dual;
  dbms_output.put_line('Value of OUTRES is' || OUTRES);
end;
/
quit
EOF
```