# Get return value of a SQL function in ksh

Tags: sql, shell, unix, plsql, ksh

I am calling a SQL function using KSH. Based on the output/return value of the function, i would like to do some checking but first I need access to that value.

Here is my KSH Code/Function:

```
# Call runSeriatimValuation Web Service
runSeriatimValuation() {

  jobNum=$1
  echo "Running Seriatim Valuation with ${jobNum}"

  # Call web service Oracle stored procedure
  ${sqlplusCmd} << END_SQLPLUS  
   WHENEVER SQLERROR EXIT SQL.SQLCODE ROLLBACK;
   WHENEVER OSERROR EXIT 9 ROLLBACK;
   DECLARE
    v_Return INT;
   BEGIN
    v_Return := CALL_IPVFBJAVA_WEBSERVICE(${jobNum});
    COMMIT;
   END;
   /
END_SQLPLUS

# This is the return value of the SQL command above if it was 
# successfully execute or not. Its not related to v_Return.

 errorCode=$?

 # If error, handle and exit
 if [ "${errorCode}" -ne "0" ] ; then
   echo "Error (${errorCode}) occurred in runSeriatimValuation when calling procedure"
   exitAgent 1
 fi

# **** Here I would like to do my if/else checking on v_Return, How can I do that ???? ***** 
# how can I assign v_Return to a variable of type int and check the value of it.

 return 0
}
```

Thanks - Your help is much appreciated.

Comment: You should change `if [ "${errorCode}" -ne "0" ]` into `if [ ${errorCode} -ne 0 ] ` (comparing int's) or `if [ "${errorCode}" != "0" ] ` (comparing strings). I do not know if that answers everything, can you `echo "errorCode=${errorCode}"` just before the if-statement and test with a correct and incorrect  code (change `COMMIT` into `AJR`).

Comment: Thanks - Good Catch. But how can I check the v_Return value ?

Comment: Can you do something like `EXIT v_Return` just after `COMMIT` ? Maybe test with `EXIT 42` so you get a clear returncode.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Shell script embedding Oracle PL/SQL code defining bind variable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21251630/shell-script-embedding-oracle-pl-sql-code-defining-bind-variable)

Answer (score 0):

You can directly check the return type like below,

`if [ $? -eq 0 ]`
`then`
`##DO Something`
`else`
`##DO Something`
`fi`

Comment: Yes I can check the return type, however that will be the return type of the SQL command executed. which I am doing in my script above. What i want is to check the value of v_Return. Thats where i am having issues with. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is set a variable and equate it to the sql command.

For example:

```
var1=${sqlplusCmd} << END_SQLPLUS  
WHENEVER SQLERROR EXIT SQL.SQLCODE ROLLBACK;
WHENEVER OSERROR EXIT 9 ROLLBACK;
select CALL_IPVFBJAVA_WEBSERVICE(${jobNum}) from dual;
commit
exit;
END_SQLPLUS
```

Answer (score 0):

What i did was the value return from SQL put it in an array and then got the first element in the array to check it.

Here is the code:

```
set -A fnOut `${sqlplusCmd} << END_SQLPLUS 
WHENEVER SQLERROR EXIT SQL.SQLCODE ROLLBACK;
WHENEVER OSERROR EXIT 9 ROLLBACK;
SET PAGESIZE 0 FEEDBACK OFF VERIFY OFF HEADING OFF ECHO OFF;
SELECT IPVOWN.CALL_IPVFBJAVA_WEBSERVICE(${jobNum}) FROM DUAL;
END_SQLPLUS`

 # Get return value
 errorCode=$?
 echo "errorCode = ${errorCode}"

 # If error, handle and exit
 if [ "${errorCode}" -ne "0" ] ; then
   echo "Error (${errorCode}) occurred in runSeriatimValuation when calling procedure"
  exitAgent 1
 fi

echo "First element in fnOut is ${fnOut[0]}"
 # If job found to be cancelled then return 1, otherwise return 0
 if [ "${fnOut[0]}" -ne "0" ] ; then
  echo "PL/SQL Procedure Failed, The return value is ${fnOut[0]}"
  exitAgent -1
 fi
```

Hope this helps.

Thanks,